# Highlight already selected items in multiple select box

Tags: php

> I have 2 tables one 'brand' that stores all the brand names and 'brand_category' that stores all the brand names with their corresponding categories. I have a multiple select box that loads all the items in the 'brand' table when the page loads, but I need to highlight the items that are already submitted by the user previously in the 'brand_category' table with the rest of the brands that are left so that the user knows what are the brands left to be entered in the 'brand_category' table. Below is the code but it doesn't work. Please help to resolve this issue

```
<div class="selectbox">
    <label id="brand" class="brand_label">Brand:</lable>
    <?php
        echo "<select name='brand' class='cat_brands' multiple>"
        <option value='0'>None</option>";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM brand");
        while($br_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $query_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand_category WHERE brand_id='".$br_query['id']."'");
            while($brnd_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_select)){
                if($brnd_select['brand_id']==$br_query['id']){
                    echo "<option style='background-color: red' value='".$br_query['id']."'>".$br_query['name']."</option>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

> The above code only displays the brands entered in the 'brand_category' table rest of the brands are not displayed. I need to display them also.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention `else` condition inside while loop.Here is the code

```
<div class="selectbox">
<label id="brand" class="brand_label">Brand:</lable>
<?php
    echo "<select name='brand' class='cat_brands' multiple>"
    <option value='0'>None</option>";
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM brand");
    while($br_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $query_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand_category WHERE brand_id='".$br_query['id']."'");
        while($brnd_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_select)){
            if($brnd_select['brand_id']==$br_query['id']){
                echo "<option style='background-color: red' value='".$br_query['id']."'>".$br_query['name']."</option>";
            }else{
               echo "<option value='".$br_query['id']."'>".$br_query['name']."</option>";
            }

        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure this would work, once in the second while loop the condition would always match the first one, and the else won't execute as the db query will always match the first

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your query correctly you are trying to pull out all the brands and to make the ones in the brands_category table to display as selected.

You should better be using MySQL PDO extensions rather than this obsolete method

There are better ways to implement this, e.g. by having just one table or by using a Join query, anyway... this should work.

```
<select name='brand' class='cat_brands' multiple>
<option value='0'>None</option>
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM brand");

while($br_query = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
   $query_select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand_category WHERE brand_id='".$br_query['id']."'");

   if(mysql_num_rows($query_select) > 0)
   {
      while($brnd_select = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_select))
      {
         echo "<option style='background-color: red' value='".$br_query['id']."' selected='selected'>".$br_query['name']."</option>";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      echo "<option style='background-color: yellow' value='".$br_query['id']."'>".$br_query['name']."</option>";
   }
} ?>
</select>
```